# Posting SAML assertion to get an OAuth token

Tags: oauth, saml

I have 2 service providers, SP1 and SP2 and I have obtained my SAML response from IDP into SP1. Now, in order to connect SP1 and SP2 I am using the oauth SAML response from SP1 and posting it to oAuth token end point (which is a connected app in SP2). Now, if I have to put user's username is the SAML assertion's Subject (in SP1), then which user would that be SP1 user or SP2 user? because these 2 username's are different only the federationId is common.